# quandl issue with Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, quandl

I have installed **quandl** via pip through Anaconda Prompt and everything seems good. But then, I can't use quandl on my PyCharm. 
I have Python 3.

I have tried several solutions, but none seem to work.

However, quandl works fine in Spyder.

Any suggestion to make it work in PyCharm?

It's very weird because even if I just type `import quandl` in PyCharm and run it, then I get the `quandl has no get attribute` error!

Comment: Hi. Sad news no. I haven't tried again as time has passed and have done some updates. Will let you know asap.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Pycharm` is using the `Python interpreter` you installed `quandl` on.

In `Pycharm` the `Interpreter Settings` are found under

```
>File, >Settings, >Project:, >Project Interpreter
```

Comment: So, what would you suggest if I have only one Python interpreter installed in my PC? I can see that there is a Quandl module listed under the selected project interpreter Anaconda3/python.exe inside my PyCharm? But no quandl...

Comment: Nop. However, import quandl yields no error. And then, when it gets to df = quandl.get("WIKI/FB"), then I get AttributeError: module 'quandl' has no attribute 'get' ...

Answer (score 0):

If `import quandl` works on python3 (terminal) or in Spider and not in Pycharm, is probably a configuration problem.

You should set the correct Python Interpreter in Pycharm settings. 
Follow this path in pyCharm:

```
File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter
```

Then, select which one that contains **quandl**.

Anyway, I suggest you a different approach: i think that the best solution is set an anaconda environment for each project. In this way you can set the project interpreter with the anaconda environment and all will work well.

To create an environment use the following command:

```
conda create -n <name> python=x.x anaconda
```

then activate it with

```
activate <name>         (Windows)
source activate <name>  (Linux)
```

install new packages in this way:

```
conda install -n <name> <package>
```

At the end deactivate environment:

```
source deactivate
```

I link this [tutorial](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) on anaconda environments.